# spark kryoserializer buffer overflow: conf not getting set

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm facing the same generic problem which I found in couple of other questions here but the resolutions suggested in all of them doesn't work for me. Also, it's a different issue of I couldn't even see the kryo value after I set it from within the Spark Shell.

Setting the property:

`conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","2048")
res1: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@463c5d0f`

Trying to see what value have been set:
`spark.sqlContext.getAllConfs.get("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max")
res2: Option[String] = None`

Not sure why I couldn't see the value I set there just now.

Also, if I do a getAll property list, I get this:
`spark.sqlContext.getAllConfs`

`scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(spark.port.maxRetries -> 20, spark.serializer -> org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer, spark.sql.warehouse.dir -> /user/hive/warehouse, spark.yarn.jars -> local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/jars/*, ...`

Can someone let me know what's the issue here? Not sure if I'm doing something wrong to set property.

Spark version: `2.2.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems its not allowed to be 2048. Got below error through spark-shell:

```
$ bin/spark-shell --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2048
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/04/03 19:33:03 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/04/03 19:33:03 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max must be less than 2048 mb, got: + 2048 mb.
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:68)
```

So, in your case, it seems to be getting silently ignored.
When I set to lesser value, it reflects:

```
scala> sc.getConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","1024")
res3: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@7d8d671b
scala> spark.sqlContext.getConf("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max")
res5: String = 1024
```

From spark config [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

> spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max
>   Maximum allowable size of Kryo
>   serialization buffer, in MiB unless otherwise specified. This must be
>   larger than any object you attempt to serialize and must be less than
>   2048m. Increase this if you get a "buffer limit exceeded" exception
>   inside Kryo.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it later. But even when I'm trying to set it up to 2047. It doesn't show anything at all. That's strange that you're getting the value of the property when you retrieve it. I don't get anything at all.

Comment: Strange. I tested on 2.1.2 and 2.3.0 (i have these installed) and it works. Wondering where the `conf.` you got (as mentioned in your Q ), where you set it.  Can you try `sc.getConf.set` instead.